# python script compiled with py2exe Import error: no module named win32com

Tags: python, py2exe, win32com

I have been reading all possible posts with the similar topic, tried all possible suggestions, still can't make it work.
the setup.py I started with was very simple,  like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['test.py'],options={"py2exe":{"dll_excludes":["MSVCP90.dll", "HID.DLL", w9xpopen.exe"],"skip_archive": [True]}})
```

test.py is compiled correctly

test.py is very simple:

```
import sys
import win32com.client #imports the pywin32 library
scope=win32com.client.Dispatch("LeCroy.ActiveDSOCtrl.1")  #creates instance of the ActiveDSO (ActiveX object) control
scope.MakeConnection("IP:127.0.0.1") #Connects to the local host
scope.WriteString("*IDN?",1)
print ("scope model: "+scope.ReadString(80))
```

I get the error right at the first line:import win32com.client

test.py itself works well
tried using additional code in setup.py as suggested at this link:http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/win32com.shell (using modulefinder)
but I am getting exactly the same error: No module named win32com

hope some one can help with this or suggest another way to compile a pythons script where this win32com.client is mandatory.
thanks

Comment: Have you tried using [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)? It's user friendly and it has solid documentation.

Answer (score 0):

win32com.client is a part of pywin32   I assume you tried:

```
  pip install pywin32
```

if that didn't work this should:

```
  pip install pypiwin32
```

Comment: For some reason I can't see my comment posted 2 days ago....anyway, the OS is windows10, and Win32com is installed. everything works well when interpreted, I mean when script is execute at command prompt or in LIClicpse. Only  the executable gives the error message reported.

Comment: after digging more into this on various forums I concluded that the problem is with Py2exe, no longer supported. I switched to Pyinstaller and everything works well... so this is  my suggestion get rid of py2exe and install pyinstaller. to do this use pip already included in the python 2.7.14 release.